# Import list of songs into Apple Music

Tags: mac, audio, itunes, mp3, music

### Import list of songs into Apple Music

---

**Context:**

---

Essentially, I've been writing down a list of songs in my note app on my Macbook Pro (more specifically, OneNote) which I like - just the name, because usually I'll know the artist and recognise the song based on the name. It's something like 100 songs long.

I just got Apple Music, and I want to create a huge playlist with all the songs on the list - only I don't want to add them one at a time.

---

**Question:**

---

Is there some way I can import a list of song names into Apple Music and mass add them into one playlist as opposed to individually adding them? Some way for apple music to recognise the song and add it?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Answer (score 0):

Apple Music is a subscription service, not an app. The app is just called Music (or iTunes on Windows).

The Music app has a TON of great AppleScript ability, but you can’t add a song by just the name. Best you could do is probably write a script to loop thru your file (export it to text first) and do a search for that song, wait a bit for you to add or skip it (in the app), then the script could move on to the next line in the file.